# Get Storage Account Name from Data Factory Linked Service

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a requirement, where I want to get the ADLS storage account name and use it in an activity. I am using Event based Trigger and I can get the container name, folder path and the file name from the trigger. But, I want the storage account name as well.

I can see that in the Linked Service JSON, it stores the storage account name in the URL. Is there any way to extract this information.

[image]

Comment: could you explain a little bit more your use case ?

Comment: so, I have to create the URL path for the blob file

Comment: If you use the linked service you just need the relative path ?

Answer (score 1):

I could suggest you to please have a look on the API which ADF exposes .

Linked Services - Get
Reference

Service:
Data Factory
API Version:
2018-06-01
Gets a linked service.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/linked-services/get

Answer (score 0):

Linked service JSON code is generated based on the values we provide while creating it. The storage account name from the JSON code cannot be pulled to use in your pipeline.

Instead, create a parameter in your pipeline to store the storage account name and pass the account name value from the trigger/linked service when creating it.

Pipeline parameter:

[image]

Passing parameter value from trigger:

[image]